# Remove snap-store without removing snapd

Tags: 19.04, snap

I tried to install snap-store but messed up in between...

When I run:

```bsh
joe@uOS:~$ snap list --all
Name               Version           Rev   Tracking  Publisher   Notes
core               16-2.42.1         8039  stable    canonical✓  core
core18             20191030          1265  stable    canonical✓  base
gtk-common-themes  0.1-25-gcc83164   1353  stable    canonical✓  -
micro              0+git.af520cf     648   stable    zy          classic
snap-store         20191114.a9948d5  209   stable    canonical✓  -

joe@uOS:~$ snap-store
realpath: '': No such file or directory
realpath: '': No such file or directory
realpath: '': No such file or directory
realpath: '': No such file or directory
realpath: '': No such file or directory
realpath: '': No such file or directory
realpath: '': No such file or directory
realpath: '': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat '/snap/snap-store/209/gnome-platform/usr/share/mime': No such file or directory
Directory '/home/joe/snap/snap-store/209/.local/share/mime/packages' does not exist!
/snap/snap-store/209/bin/desktop-launch: line 10: /snap/snap-store/209/gnome-platform/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3-0/gtk-query-immodules-3.0: No such file or directory
ERROR: update-mime-database /home/joe/snap/snap-store/209/.local/share/mime exited abnormally with status 1
ERROR: /snap/snap-store/209/gnome-platform/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3-0/gtk-query-immodules-3.0 exited abnormally with status 127
04:49:21:0766 GLib-GIO g_app_info_get_name: assertion 'G_IS_APP_INFO (appinfo)' failed
04:49:21:0766 Gtk Locale not supported by C library.
    Using the fallback 'C' locale.
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
04:49:21:0769 Gtk cannot open display: :0

joe@uOS:~$ sudo snap remove snap-store
error: snap "snap-store" has "install-snap" change in progress
```

How can I remove / reinstall snap-store without affecting other snap packages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh.. I just did it...
I ran

```bsh
joe@uOS:~$ sudo snap remove gtk-common-themes
gtk-common-themes removed
joe@uOS:~$ snap list --all
Name             Version                     Rev   Tracking  Publisher   Notes
core             16-2.42.1                   8039  stable    canonical✓  core
core18           20191030                    1265  stable    canonical✓  base
gnome-3-28-1804  3.28.0-16-g27c9498.27c9498  110   stable    canonical✓  -
micro            0+git.af520cf               648   stable    zy          classic
snap-store       20191114.a9948d5            209   stable    canonical✓  -
joe@uOS:~$ sudo snap remove snap-store
snap-store removed

joe@uOS:~$ sudo snap install gtk-common-themes
gtk-common-themes 0.1-25-gcc83164 from Canonical✓ installed
joe@uOS:~$ sudo snap install snap-store
snap-store 20191114.a9948d5 from Canonical✓ installed
```

Perfect it runs... but I wonder why did that ever happen...