# Don't have Ubuntu Software Center, on Jammy, and I wan it back

Tags: snap, snap-store

I use Ubuntu Jammy. The SnapStore app needed update but it wasn't possible to update because apps were running and I can't remember the exact notification. The thing is that was going to be expired (sorry, not the correct word) in 8 days. I tried to delete SnapStore from the Ubuntu Software Center but was taking forever to load the Installed screen and I decided to delete it from Terminal. I looked into Ask Ubuntu and I find the question matching (?) my issue and I used: sudo apt autoremove --purge snapd
Believeing that my problem was going to be solved and the new version of the Software Center will appear. But no. . . .
Without any GUI tools I tried to install Brave browser following Brave's instructions without success.
Please, how can I get back Ubuntu Software so I can install apps successfull.THANK YOU!

Comment: Providing details of what you actually did would allow us to better understand your position. If you used commands, your command history should remind you what you did & thus how to revert your changes, if you used GUI tools (or commands too), logs will tell you what packages changes were made. You need to revert changes you've made but not told us what you actually did, or how you did it.

Comment: "*I read here*" is vague: It doesn't tell us what you did. For most folks reinstalling snap-store is as simple as `sudo snap install snap-store` Please downvote an answer that tells you to uninstall a snap instead of how to simply refresh it.

Comment: You can install Firefox without snaps, using the mozilla trusted ppa. https://www.kubuntuforums.net/forum/general/documentation/how-to-s/662503-how-to-set-priority-for-a-ppa-i-e-using-firefox-without-snapd & https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/04/how-to-install-firefox-deb-apt-ubuntu-22-04 & https://launchpad.net/~mozillateam/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

Comment: you removed `snapd` entirely, so no snaps can run or be installed. You can reinstall `snapd` using `sudo apt install snapd` and then install snap-store and any other snaps you want. In the future, the worst that will happen if you ignore the update notifications is that the app will close on its own and update itself eventually. In the case of snap store, that is most likely no big deal (of course you could close it on your own, and it would update itself).

Comment: I installed Chrome and Brave via Terminal. Still don't have Ubuntu Software Center :(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove snap-store without removing snapd](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1193674/remove-snap-store-without-removing-snapd)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved
sudo snap install snap-store

Thank you for your help. :)